# Problem sending an array containing some JSON string to AJAX from PHP

Tags: php, ajax, data-transfer

Am working on a form whereby am passing values from the frontend to the backend using AJAX. From the frontend, all the data is being passed fine except that after performing some logic on the backend, I need to transport the data to the frontend.  The data is contained in 2 separate variables whereby I have converted each to a JSON object for transmission.
When I dd() the data in the backend I get it in form of a string.

The problem is when I log response in the console tab (from the AJAX code), I don't get any response from the backend.. Please assist?

**Controller file containing PHP code**

```
public
    function validatePlanEntries(Request $request)
    {   
        //dd($request->all());

        //Other PHP logic

        //Convert data to JSON format
        $form = json_encode($oldata);

        //dd($form);

        $planJson = json_encode($plans_benefits);

        $plans = compact(['planJson' , 'form']);
        //dd($plans);
        return $plans;
    }
```

**AJAX code getting the response from the controller above**

```
 <script>
        //Other Js code

       form.parsley().validate();

      //Returns true if Parsley validation has no errors
      if (form.parsley().isValid()){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getplans",
            data:JSON.stringify(type),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            failure: function(errMsg) {
                 alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
      };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't convert them to 2 separate JSON encoded values an instead add them to 1.  So instead of...

```
//Convert data to JSON format
$form = json_encode($oldata);

//dd($form);

$planJson = json_encode($plans_benefits);

$plans = compact(['planJson' , 'form']);
//dd($plans);
return $plans;
```

Something like, build an array with both pieces of data and `json_encode()` the result...

```
return json_encode([ "form" => $oldata, "plan" => $plans_benefits]);
```

You will need to update your Javascript to extract the relevant parts of the response.

**Update:**

I'm not a Laravel person, but it seems you can use...

```
return \Response::json([ "form" => $oldata, "plan" => $plans_benefits]);
```

Comment: Okay fine,, but when I log it in console tab from the AJAX code, I dont get any response

Comment: When I dd() I get the response well as a JSON string but when I use return keyword to direct  it back to AJAX code and log the response I dont see anything

Comment: return don't work in ajax.user print_r to get response

Comment: Are you using a framework to process your responses, how does that return data?

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy I want to redirect the data to AJAX inside success,, how will print_r solve this

Comment: @NigelRen The PHP logic is writen in Laravel framework

Comment: @NigelRen I used the same AJAX code for posting data to the function,, am now using return keyword to transmit the data back to AJAX success

Comment: Always worth in your question mentioning if your using a specific framework as people will be able to offer you expert help (rather than me using Google :-/)